# Update a value of a duplicate rows in access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in Access that has rows with some duplicates. I would like to update one of the columns of all duplicates excluding the first one.

Table:

| ID | person_id | id_addr | note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 12 |  |
| 2 | 2 | 12 | d |
| 3 | 1 | 34 |  |
| 4 | 3 | 45 |  |
| 5 | 3 | 45 | d |
| 6 | 3 | 45 | d |

thats what i would like to have as a result.
In MS Access (2007-2016).

Comment: Will id_addr always be same for each person_id?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by duplicate you mean both [person_id] and [id_addr], create a formula based on these two fields to make a unique value, for example: `[person_id]*10000+[id_addr]`. Use this value to group the results of a query to get the first (minimum in this case) `ID` in each group:

```
SELECT Min([ID]) 
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY [person_id]*10000+[id_addr]
```

The result of this query would be like following:

| first ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

Then use these results as excluded IDs in an update query:

```
UPDATE [Table] SET [note]="d"
WHERE [ID] NOT IN (
    SELECT Min([ID]) FROM [Table]
    GROUP BY [person_id]*10000+[id_addr])
```

Comment: I would use Min instead of First. However, both provide same result for this case.

Comment: @June7, Thanks for the point, you are absolutely correct. `Min` is more sensible. I will update the code.